# Unable to resolve segmentation Fault in C program

Tags: c, pointers

My assignment is to write a C function void censor(char *start) that will replace all 4 letter words in the string pointed to by start with ****. Assume that words are delimited by blank chars. The
beginning and the end of strings are also delimiters. I am not to use [ ] in your code.
For example, the following code:

```
int main(){
char myStr[50] = ”this is a test for the last word in line”;
censor(myStr);
printf(”%s\n”, myStr);
}
would yield:
**** is a **** for the **** **** in ****
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* findBlank(char *start)
{   char *tempStart = start;
    while(*tempStart != '\0') {
        if(*tempStart == ' ') {
            return tempStart;
        }
        tempStart++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void fourStars(char *start)
{
    char *tempStart = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        *tempStart = '*';
        tempStart++;
    }
}

void censor(char *start)
{   
    char *temp;

    while(*start != '\0') {
        int len = 0;
        temp = findBlank(start);
        while(start < temp && *start != '\0'){
            len++;
            start++;
        }

        if(len == 4) {
            char *replace = temp - len;
            fourStars(replace);
        }
        
        if ((*start != '\0') || (*(temp+1) != '\0')) {
            start = temp + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    char myStr[50] = "this is a test for the last word in line";
    censor(myStr);
    printf("%s\n", myStr);

}
```

I tried running it through the gdb debugger and also trying to trace it but I am unable to resolve this.
Here was the output from the gdb debugger:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555527c in censor (start=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at main.c:29
29          while(*start != '\0') {
```

I'm not allowed to change the functionality of my findBlank or fourStars functions.

Comment: Why is your **C** program tagged with `c++`?

Comment: Why are you returning `NULL` from `findBlank`?

Comment: Looks like `findBlank()` returned NULL. Then `start = temp + 1;` executed causing start to be 1. Then you tried to dereference start with `while(*start != '\0') {`

Comment: Here I've built your program with some extra diagnostic output: https://godbolt.org/z/Eevn753od . **SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000001** translates to English as "Null Pointer (plus offset)  accessed."  and the stack trace tells you where: line 29. The next step is to take a look at `while(*start != '\0')` with a debugger and see what the value of `start` is. Then I'd run the program again but approach line 29 more slowly, so I can see how the pointer went so wrong.

Comment: @Eljay sorry it was a mistake I have removed it.

Comment: @dbush I meant to return a NULL if the function does not find any space

Comment: Then the problem is figuring out what the program does after `findBlank` hits the end of the string without finding a space and changing it to do what it needs to do, which is probably scan that last token in the string, if any, and exit.

Comment: I tried a few ways to handle the null pointer when temp reaches the end of the string and finds no space, however, none of them seem to be working or causing any changes. @user4581301

Comment: I'd start by following `temp = findBlank(start);` with `if (!temp) return;`. In English, if `findBlank` didn't find anything, there's nothing to be found, but this will likely drop the last token. But what if you process the last token and then leave? Something like `do { process token } while (temp !=NULL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program segfaults on `while(*start != '\0')` as `start == 1`.  It was assigned that value from `start = temp + 1` so `temp == NULL`.  `temp` is `NULL` when `findBlank()` doesn't find any spaces.  If you want the last 4 letter word censored then the minimal fix is for `findBlank()` return a pointer to the '\0' instead of NULL:

```
char *findBlank2(char *start) {
    for(; *start && *start != ' '; start++);
    return start;
}
```

and example run:

```
**** is a **** for the **** **** in ****
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to handle this within the censor function without altering the findBlank function as that is one of the requirements of my assignment to not change the findBlank and fourStars functions as they are taken from previous questions.

Comment: @goldengomi sadly it may be too late for that now that the question has been answered with an answer that was correct at the time it was posted. Allan may throw you a bone, well within his rights to do so, but in general, moving the goalposts of a question is frowned upon. When you have an important restriction like that, It needs to be in the question before people start answering it.

Comment: The appropriate action at this point is to accept the answer of  the original question.  Then submit a new revised question with those additional constraints if you still need help.  The only difference between the original `findBlank()` and my version (let's call it `findBlank2()`) is that it `findBlank()` returns NULL if no spaces are found. You could patch that up like this `temp = findBlank(start); if(!temp) temp = start + strlen(start) ;`

Answer (score 1):

The `findBlank` function returns `NULL` when a `\0` null terminator is reached, but `censor` does not handle this case correctly. All of the code that follows `temp = findBlank(start)` and which uses `temp` is problematic because the possibility that `temp` is `NULL` has not been considered.

Looking first at `char *replace = temp - len;`, this has undefined behavior since both the result of subtracting an integer value from a pointer and the original pointer must point to the elements of the same array object (or one past the end of the array object). When `temp` is `NULL` this is not true. Even in the absence of undefined behavior this line makes no sense when `temp` has been set to `NULL`. A solution is to avoid incrementing `start` directly while iterating over words; then you can just use `start` when calling `fourStars`. This can be accomplished by incrementing `len` only, and adding `len` to `start` when necessary.

Next, consider:

```
while(start < temp && *start != '\0'){
    len++;
    start++;
}
```

When `temp` has been set to `NULL`, this code makes no sense. A solution is to handle two cases: when `temp` is `NULL`, the end of the input string has been reached and iteration should proceed until the `\0` terminator is found. Otherwise a space was found and iteration should proceed until `temp` is reached. While doing these iterations, `len` should be incremented but `start` should not be changed. The pointer formed by `start + len` has the same value as the pointer kept by continually incrementing with `start++`.

Finally consider:

```
if ((*start != '\0') || (*(temp+1) != '\0')) {
    start = temp + 1;
}
```

This contains the problematic expression `temp + 1`. There is no need for this conditional at all anymore. Just set `start` with `start = start + len + 1` to increment the `start` pointer to the next location.

With these changes the `findBlank` and `fourStars` functions remain unchanged. Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* findBlank(char *start)
{
    char *tempStart = start;
    while(*tempStart != '\0') {
        if(*tempStart == ' ') {
            return tempStart;
        }
        tempStart++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void fourStars(char *start)
{
    char *tempStart = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        *tempStart = '*';
        tempStart++;
    }
}

void censor(char *start)
{   
    char *temp;

    while(*start != '\0') {
        int len = 0;

        temp = findBlank(start);  // `temp` is `NULL` when \0 was reached

        if (temp == NULL) {
            while (*(start+len) != '\0') {
                len++;
            }
        } else {
            while((start+len) < temp) {
                len++;
            }
        }

        if(len == 4) {
            fourStars(start);
        }
        
        start = start + len + 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char myStr[50] = "this is a test for the last word in line";
    censor(myStr);
    printf("%s\n", myStr);

}
```

And here is the result of running the program:

```
$ ./findblank
**** is a **** for the **** **** in ****
```